# Power BI - Use slicer to fetch file from folder

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, slicers

I have files in a folder which have same structure. The only difference between them is that for each day a new file is created which is named as date of the day.

So if file is created on 11th November 2019, its name would be 11092019.xlsx.

I have created a slicer which fetches names of all files present in this folder.

Keeping in mind that file format is same and only difference is in their file name and data values in them. **Is there any way so that when I select a value from slicer the respective files data will be displayed in table visual ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to load a file interactively based on the slicer value.

You can achieve this by,

- Load all files in the folder.
- Combine them into a single table, where you need to add a "File Name" column.
- Use slicer to show records coming from the specific file.

Comment: Nice turnaround. But the data in each file have some defined order. Now if I slice based on file name as you suggested, the data order is getting disturbed. Any way to keep the order intact ?

Comment: How about adding a index column with `Table.AddIndexColumn`, and use that column in "Sort by Column"?

Comment: But then I have to add index column in file itself which is not feasible for multiple files.

Comment: You don't need to modify the files. It should be done within PowerQuery, and only Power BI in-memory data will have the index column.